# How to set UI for all Components of a type in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, custom-component

I created my own `MyScrollbarUI` class to have a custom scrollbar look in my application. Now I have to do

```
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUI(new MyScrollbarUI());
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new MyScrollbarUI());
```

on any `ScrollPane` I use.

Is it somehow possible to tell `Swing` that it should use `MyScrollbarUI` on any scrollbar. Maybe via the `UIManager`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", MyScrollbarUI.class.getName());
```

should do the trick.

You need to have a `public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c)` method in your UI class, returning an instance of your UI.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the method I often forget to implement :-) no need for the getDefaults, though

Comment: OK. I trust you on this (and basically on everything regarding Swing). I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your custom UI class as `ScrollPaneUI` property of [`UIManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html). By default it is `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollPaneUI` change it to your custom class.

Answer (score 2):

technically, it's as easy as to tell the UIManager which delegate to use (as @Harry Joy already mentioned), like

```
 UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", "fully-qualified-className-of-customUI")
```

This will effectively install the same delegate class for all LAFs which might result less than optimal visuals in all except the one you extended your custom ui-class from. Strictly, you need one custom class per LAF

Answer (score 0):

Make new ScrollPane component by extending JScrollPane and tell your custom ScrollPane to use MyScrollbarUI. Then modify all your code to use your custom ScrollPane instead of JScrollPane.

Comment: wrong - swing is designed to support _pluggable_ ui-delegates, no need to subclass any view